# Dataframe: access elements with index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe whose rows and columns are labelled with indices:

```
0    1    1    14   14   14   14   ...  327  327  327  327  327  327  327
14     0    0    0    0    1    1    1  ...    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
14     0    0    0    1    1    1    1  ...    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
14     0    0    0    0    1    1    1  ...    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
14     0    0    0    1    1    1    1  ...    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
14     0    0    0    1    1    0    1  ...    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
..   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
327    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
327    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
327    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...    1    1    0    0    0    1    1
327    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
327    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  ...    0    0    0    0    0    0    1

[18349 rows x 1233 columns]
```

If I want to access the elements of the rows labelled with 14 the command is:

```
df.loc['14']
```

I would like to get the elements in a cycle, where the variable to cycle is the index of the rows.
What I tried is:

```
for i in labels:
    a = df.loc[str(i)]
```

where *labels* is the vector of the labels, but this does not work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: if you want to fetch data based on row/column index, you can use `iloc` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group in every loop your subdataframe, you need to loop over unique indices.

```py
for index in df.index.unique():
    subdf = df.loc[index]
```

If you want, however, to loop over unique indices also found in columns, you need to intersect both arrays.

```py
for index in df.index.unique().intersection(df.columns):
    # this index is found both on rows and columns
    subdf = df.loc[index]
```

Comment: What if I wanted to loop over the unique indeces that are common for both rows and columns? (Rows and columns have different number of labels and some are different, while I want to loop only on the common ones)

Comment: @Dario Edited answer